# Powershell Import-Module not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I have a basic powershell module below that works fine if I call it as a powershell script however I can't get it to work as a module.

**Get-Info.psm1**

```
function Get-Info
{
    param($ComputerName)
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_BIOS
}

Get-Info -ComputerName localhost
```

So when attempting to get this to work as a module I use the code above and use `Import-Module .\Get-Info.psm1` to import the module. I get no errors when importing the module. There is no output at all.

When I run `Get-Info` as a command I get the error below:

```
Get-Info : The term 'Get-Info' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Info
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Info:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Does anyone know how to get the module to run correctly?

Comment: are you working thru this article? >>> Powershell: Building a Module, one microstep at a time — https://powershellexplained.com/2017-05-27-Powershell-module-building-basics/ <<< if so, you need to leave the actual call to the function OUT of the PSM1 file.

Comment: I was working through that module. I can't see where in the article it says that though. If I don't put them in the psm1 file where do they go?

Comment: i am referring to the last line in your code - >>> `Get-Info -ComputerName localhost` <<< that is how you _call_ the function, not part of the module. you will note that the "Dot sourcing" and the "Import-Module" section show the call AFTER the dot-source or import-module line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never realized how stupid I was being. I would upvote these comments if I could but I only seem to be able to flag them.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help ... and your thanks are quite sufficient. [*grin*]